# Clearing database logs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, database, sql, log

We've recently migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and it seems that there is a large amount of information in our database files.

We'd like to try to mitigate this by clearing the log files but unlike Magento 1, there does not seem to be a built in facility to do this in Magento 2.

Is there a way to clean out the log files in the database in Magento 2 so that we can hopefully free up some space.

Our database is accessible through phpmyadmin if that helps.

Comment: have you tried exporting it with gzipped compression ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid that it came up with the following:  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "log" namespace.

  Did you mean one of these?
      catalog:product:attributes
      catalog:product
      catalog:images
      catalog
      dev:query-log
      dev:urn-catalog

Comment: @ShoaibMunir, I think this command is not exist php bin/magento log:clean  .where you got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are the tables you can clear/exclude from dumping:

- "email_abandoned_cart"
- "email_automation"
- "email_campaign"
- "email_contact"
- "persistent_session"
- "report_compared_product_index"
- "report_event"
- "report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily"
- "report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly"
- "report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly"
- "report_viewed_product_index"
- "session"